# Consented permissions not working when using Microsoft Graph Explorer to access reports

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access reports from Graph API using the Graph Explorer. However, it throws 403 Unauthorised errors.

For example the request:

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30')

throws the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "S2SUnauthorized",
        "message": "Invalid permission.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "fda8c3ec-1949-46a9-b179-e1017f7e94ab",
            "date": "2020-04-02T01:01:08"
        }
    }
}:
```

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0) this requires the permissions 'Reports.Read.All'
When looking at the permissions I have in the explorer it says that [Reports.Read.All permission is 'consented'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHWJW.png)

This worked without issues in early December when I was first testing this, so unless something changed I don't know what is going on.

Am I misunderstanding what consented means in this context, or is this a problem with the Graph Explorer as this permission is marked as 'preview'?

Regardless of the source of the problem, does anyone know a way around this/how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure,

- try repro the above using MS Graph Explorer with your tenant!!
- if you're using delegated permissions to allow apps to read service usage reports on behalf of a user, the tenant administrator must have assigned the user the appropriate Azure AD limited administrator role

Let me know still you can repro the issue.

Comment: Hi Ryan, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks for your answer and sorry it took so long to get back to you. I still cannot access the reports, but judging by your last statement my level of access may be the issue. We are using delegated permissions and I do not have even limited tenant admin rights. 
The part that confused me most is that this worked last year (when I also had the same permission level) so something must have changed with either graph explorer or the tenancy's permission landscape.
It is a shared tenancy, so there is no way I'm going to get admin rights, so we are going to try an alternative approach.